# images inside recyclerview being invisible onscroll

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to read if there is any image or not, then if image is null, I make the imageview in post card gone. If not then load it using Glide.

It works when I load the recyclerview for first time. But after some scrolls, those imageviews get invisible(View.gone)

onBindViewHolder:

```
DataSnapshot d = topics.get(position);
    holder.text.setText(d.child("caption").getValue(String.class));
    if (d.child("type").getValue(String.class)!=null&&d.child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("image")){
        Glide.with(c).load(d.child("image").getValue(String.class)).placeholder(R.drawable.background).centerCrop().into(holder.image);
    }
    else{
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    holder.name.setText(d.child("username").getValue(String.class));
    holder.category.setText(d.child("category").getValue(String.class));
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long posttime = d.child("time").getValue(Long.class);
    long timedifference = millis-posttime;
    int days = (int) (timedifference / (1000*60*60*24));
    if (days<2){
        holder.time.setText("Today");

    }else {
        holder.time.setText(days+" days ago");

    }
    if (d.child("pic").exists()){
        Glide.with(c).load(d.child("pic").getValue(String.class)).placeholder(R.drawable.background).centerCrop().into(holder.pic);
    }
```

So where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this code snippet :**

```
if (d.child("type").getValue(String.class)!=null&&d.child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("image")){
      Glide.with(c).load(d.child("image").getValue(String.class)).placeholder(R.drawable.background).centerCrop().into(holder.image);
      holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else{
      holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

> When you are setting visibility gone it won't be visible by it self.
>   you need to visible it when glide load the image and gone when image
>   is null.

Add `holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in **if condition**.

Comment: I thought it doesn't affect those specific positions where image is not null.  And yeah that code worked for me. Thank you so much.. I can accept it as answer after 5 minutes..

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 6):

It is better to set the visibility first in your case as you are passing the image view to Glide to setup.

We never know what will happen with the glide library update, in case it library wants to access the dimensions. Especially you are making it `GONE` in else part, which is a bit different from making `INVISIBLE`.

```
if (d.child("type").getValue(String.class)!=null&&d.child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("image")){
      holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(c).load(d.child("image").getValue(String.class)).placeholder(R.drawable.background).centerCrop().into(holder.image);

                }
                else{
                    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

`RecyclerView` creates new views first time for first visible data objects and when you scroll to load other items it reuses those views which has been scrolled to top and reuses those views again for new data items.

So whatever the *visibility* status of that view was when it was created for the first time, it will get retain and will be used for the other items as well.

What you need to do is to set the view `VISIBLE` explicitly to show it again:

```
if (d.child("type").getValue(String.class)!=null&&d.child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("image")){
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            Glide.with(c).load(d.child("image").getValue(String.class)).placeholder(R.drawable.background).centerCrop().into(holder.image);
            }
            else{
                holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```